# Websocket connection fails

Tags: websocket, server, ngrok, vonage

I have created websocket Ngrok listeners for the port 8000.
Now i have changed 8000 port as my public URL like(http://host:8000). 
But i mentioned in my program like `"ws://"+host+"/socket"`.

> The problem is websocket fails when i use my public URL as listener instead of using NGROK listener on the port 8000 it's working perfect.

```
var WEB_SOCKET = 'ws://' + process.env.WEB_SOCKET_URL + '/socket';
```

Is there any possibility to change ws into http for websocket ????

Answer (score 0):

Websockets are a subset/extension of the http protocol anyway so using `ws://` on your URL is correct for the Nexmo websocket connection.

Its a bit hard to know what the issue is without seeing the full code, can you log out what the value is for `process.env.WEB_SOCKET_URL` are you sure you've not put the protocol handler in that varible?

Other things to check are that port 8000 is open to the internet through any firewalls and port forwarding?

Comment: My problem was not in code. Is i am using ws:// instead of http:// or http:// instead of ws:// ...??

Comment: you should use `ws://` for the websocket URL in the Nexmo NCCO, this will run over an HTTP connection

Comment: I have used ws:// for Websocket URL like ("ws://WebsocketURL/socket").But i received events from nexmo as **failed to connect**. And one more thing i was making a call using same URL like (["http://publicURL/events"]), I get successfully response from nexmo .. why its happens ??? i am confusing tooo much ......